# Symfony2: Make users complete registration after login if some fields are missing

Tags: symfony, oauth, symfony-2.1, hwioauthbundle

I'm using HWIOAuthBundle to let an user login with Oauth, I've created a custom user provider which creates an user in case it doesn't exist:

```
public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
{
    $attr = $response->getResponse();
    switch($response->getResourceOwner()->getName()) {
        case 'google':
            if(!$user = $this->userRepository->findOneByGoogleId($attr['id'])) {
                if(($user = $this->userRepository->findOneByEmail($attr['email'])) && $attr['verified_email']) {
                    $user->setGoogleId($attr['id']);
                    if(!$user->getFirstname()) {
                        $user->setFirstname($attr['given_name']);
                    }
                    if(!$user->getLastname()) {
                        $user->setLastname($attr['family_name']);
                    }
                    $user->setGoogleName($attr['name']);
                }else{
                    $user = new User();
                    $user->setUsername($this->userRepository->createUsernameByEmail($attr['email']));
                    $user->setEmail($attr['email']);
                    $user->setFirstname($attr['given_name']);
                    $user->setLastname($attr['family_name']);
                    $user->setPassword('');
                    $user->setIsActive(true);
                    $user->setGoogleId($attr['id']);
                    $user->setGoogleName($attr['name']);
                    $user->addGroup($this->groupRepository->findOneByRole('ROLE_USER'));
                    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'facebook':
            if(!$user = $this->userRepository->findOneByFacebookId($attr['id'])) {
                if(($user = $this->userRepository->findOneByEmail($attr['email'])) && $attr['verified']) {
                    $user->setFacebookId($attr['id']);
                    if(!$user->getFirstname()) {
                        $user->setFirstname($attr['first_name']);
                    }
                    if(!$user->getLastname()) {
                        $user->setLastname($attr['last_name']);
                    }
                    $user->setFacebookUsername($attr['username']);
                }else{
                    $user = new User();
                    $user->setUsername($this->userRepository->createUsernameByEmail($attr['email']));
                    $user->setEmail($attr['email']);
                    $user->setFirstname($attr['first_name']);
                    $user->setLastname($attr['last_name']);
                    $user->setPassword('');
                    $user->setIsActive(true);
                    $user->setFacebookId($attr['id']);
                    $user->setFacebookUsername($attr['username']);
                    $user->addGroup($this->groupRepository->findOneByRole('ROLE_USER'));
                    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    $this->entityManager->flush();


    if (null === $user) {
        throw new AccountNotLinkedException(sprintf("User '%s' not found.", $attr['email']));
    }

    return $user;
}
```

The problem is that twitter for example doesn't give the email or i want some additional fields to be included before a new user is created. Is there a way to redirect an user to a "complete registration" form before creating it?

I've tried to add a request listener, that on each request, if the user is logged, checks if the email is there and if it doesn't it redirects to the complete_registration page, but it will redirect also if the user goes to the homepage, to logout or anything else, I want to redirect him only if he tries to access some user restricted pages.

Or better, don't create it until he gives all the required informations.

Comment: @elnur what did you edited? just to know if there was something wrong

Comment: Click on the last edit timestamp and see for yourself.

Comment: What a rude answer, bad mood today uh?

Comment: No. I've just taught you to fish instead of giving you a fish. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself, I've manually created a new exception:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Exception;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\Exception\OAuthAwareExceptionInterface;

/**
 * IncompleteUserException is thrown when the user isn't fully registered (e.g.: missing some informations).
 *
 * @author Alessandro Tagliapietra http://www.alexnetwork.it/
 */
class IncompleteUserException extends AuthenticationException implements OAuthAwareExceptionInterface
{
    private $user;
    private $accessToken;
    private $resourceOwnerName;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setAccessToken($accessToken)
    {
        $this->accessToken = $accessToken;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAccessToken()
    {
        return $this->accessToken;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getResourceOwnerName()
    {
        return $this->resourceOwnerName;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setResourceOwnerName($resourceOwnerName)
    {
        $this->resourceOwnerName = $resourceOwnerName;
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser($user)
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->user,
            $this->accessToken,
            $this->resourceOwnerName,
            parent::serialize(),
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($str)
    {
        list(
            $this->user,
            $this->accessToken,
            $this->resourceOwnerName,
            $parentData
        ) = unserialize($str);
        parent::unserialize($parentData);
    }
}
```

In this way, in the custom Oauth user provider when i check if an user exist or I create a new user i check if the required fields are missing:

```
if (!$user->getEmail()) {
    $e = new IncompleteUserException("Your account doesn't has a mail set");
    $e->setUser($user);
    throw $e;
}
```

In that case the user will be redirected to the login form, with that exception in session, so in the login page I do:

```
if($error instanceof IncompleteUserException) {
    $session->set(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $error);
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('register_complete'));
}
```

And it will be redirected to a form with the $user in the exception so it can ask only for the missing information and then login the user.

Comment: **This solution is not very elegant**, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue while migrating to a sf site. After the migration I wanted the migrated users to complete their profile whereas the newly registered users could get started immediately.

I solved this similar to your idea using a RequestListener but added a whitelist of pages that the user is allowed without completion of his profile. Depending on the number of pages you want the user to have access to without completion of his profile you might also consider using a blacklist.

I did not check for th existance of a particular field uppon redirecting to the profile completion page but added a role "ROLE_MIGRATION" when migrating the usersdatabase. In your case you can add the role when creating the user through oauth.

Here the code of my request listener:

```
public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $evt)
{

    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $evt->getRequestType())
    {
        return;
    }

    $token = $this->securityContext->getToken();

    if(!is_object($token)) or not migrating
    {
        // user is not logged in
        return;
    }

    $user = $token->getUser();

    if(!$user instanceof User || !$user->hasRole('ROLE_MIGRATING'))
    {
        // different user class or already migrated
        return;
    }

    $openPaths = array(
        '/start-2.0',
        '/css',
        '/js',
        '/images',
        '/media',
        '/geo',
        '/_wdt',
        '/logout', or not migrating
        '/terms',
        '/contact',
        '/about',
        '/locale/set'
    );

    foreach($openPaths as $p)
    {
        if(strpos($evt->getRequest()->getPathInfo(),$p)===0)
        {
            // path is open for migrating users
            return;
        }
    }



    header('Location: /start-2.0');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I think creating an exception when logging in should be a better way, I'll do some tests this night and post ah answer tomorrow if I get something good! Because your approach should be changed every time you add some public pages and I'm not just running a migration, but thanks for the reply..